# Sql multiple reservations and duplicate vallues

Tags: sql, ms-access

Lets assume that we have a table named `Reserations( PK, clientID, ORDER_NUMBER, CREDIT_CARD )`. A client can make multiple reservations but a reservation is considered complete when `CREDIT_CARD` is not null ( meaning that the client has prepaid the order ) visa, mastercard,etc..

So we have this table full of reservations and I want to clean it up by the following rules: if a client has made a valid reservation ( credit card is not NULL ) then if this client has other reservations that are not paid ( the credit card is null ) I will auto reserve them for him( meaning that I will add the credit card type in the `CREDIT_CARD` columns that are null for this specific client ). Otherwise the client is not valid( not a single valid credit card ) his records will be deleted.

How do I implement this in SQL microsoft access? My thoughts are : 
select the table, remove the duplicates and update the records. The only problem here is how do I know if there is at least one valid reservation made? Maybe use a count function to count the valid reservations for each client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you have to use the following queries for this.
First delete all the reservations for the client who has not made any reservation (CREDIT_CARD IS NULL), using the following query

```
    DELETE Reserations
    FROM Reserations R 
    WHERE clientID NOT IN (SELECT clientID FROM Reserations WHERE CREDIT_CARD IS NOT NULL)
```

Then update all the reservation where the credit card is null, by the credit card which is available for the paid reservations, using the following query

```
UPDATE Reserations 
SET CREDID_CARD = (SELECT TOP(1) CREDIT_CARD 
                   FROM Reserations R1 
                   WHERE R1.ClientId = R.ClientId 
                         AND R1.CREDID_CARD IS NOT NULL)
FROM Reserations R 
WHERE CREDID_CARD IS NULL
```

Comment: God thanks a lot ! this seems to work just fine. Can i ask you something ? when you say Reserations R it means that R is reserations rights? ( renaming if i am not mistaken ) and top(1) is ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: R is just alias to Reservations, in the second query it is used to join with the inner query. TOP(1) is to return a single row which contains the credit card  information for the clientid. You have to use TOP(1) here otherwise update throws error if the client has multiple records with credit_card is not null

Comment: My friend, thanks for the explanation it really helped me! P.s wanted to thumps up but my reputation is lower than 15 :(

Comment: Done that, um something crossed my mind. Since we have 2 differenct queries then R1 wont recognize R since its in a different query am i wright ?

Comment: R1 does not conflict with R. The outer query is visible in the inner query, but inner query is not visible outer